# How to assign 1st dimension of a 2D array to a pointer

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unsafe-pointers

I have a 2D array and I am trying to assign the 1st dimension of that 2D array to a pointer like below but that doesn't work.

`fixed (byte* fixedInput = array2D[0])`

How can I assign only the first dimension like I am trying to do to `fixedInput`?

`fixedInput` will then be a 1 dimensional pointer array with all info from the 1st dimension of `array2D`

Thank you!

```
    unsafe static void testFunction()
    {
        byte[,] array2D = new byte[10, 100];

        fixed (byte* fixedInput = array2D[0])
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It is a pointer into memory. The data of a 2D array is arranged in the way that the last dimension is in a sequence, in locations direclty behind eachother.

When you get a pointer, you are following the memory the way it is filled in.

If you want to read data along the other dimension, you'll need to step with strides, skipping each line.

```
public unsafe static void testFunction()
{
    uint[,] array2D = new uint[10, 100];
    for(int x=0;x<100;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
            array2D[y,x] = (uint)(1000u*y+x);
    }

    // read some data along first dimension.
    fixed (uint* fixedInput = &array2D[1,90])
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}",fixedInput[j*100]));
}
```

The data from the sample-array is arranged in memory this way:

```
0   1   2   3   4 [...] 99  1000  1001  1002 [...]
```